# How to show a modal window after button click in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity and C# programming. I just want to know how to open a modal window on button click.

```
public class Buttonwindow: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void clicked(Button button)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button click!");

    }
}
```

What code will be going in here to show a pop up window? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Unity 5?

Comment: Yes! I am using UNITY 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `yourModelWindowPanel.SetActive(true)` to enable/show your Window and pass in `false` to the `SetActive` function to hide it. This could be a panel with UI components under it.

```
public class Buttonwindow: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject modalWindow;
    public void clicked(Button button)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button click!");
        modalWindow.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: also dont forget to drag the script on the onclick in inspector of your modelwindowpanel object

Answer (score 4):

In the Scene, right click -> UI -> Canvas to create a canvas(All UI elements should be in a Canvas)
Then right click in the canvas that your created and then UI-> the element that you want(Text maybe works for your purpouse)

Then as @Programmer said

```
public class Buttonwindow: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject modalWindow;
    public void clicked(Button button)
    {
    Debug.Log("Button click!");
    modalWindow.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the modalWindow to your object in the **Inspector**

I can't comment due to my reputation, but this answer is only an improvement to the real answer by @Programmer.

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) is a tutorial for Unity UI.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these "answers" actually answer the question. A modal window is a window that maintains focus and nothing else can be done until the user clicks a button to satisfy a condition such as yes/no. That means that while a modal window is active, nothing else can have focus. A modal window cannot be navigated away from.

To make a modal window, any buttons within the panel must be set to explicit navigation and set so that they can only navigate to other buttons within the panel.

If there is only one button within the panel, set the navigation to none.

Answer (score 2):

To answer @Ba'al consern you can use this script to lock all non child interactables to get that modal effect with keyboard/controller navigation.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Legend
{
    public class ModalLocker : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Selectable[] selectables;

        void OnEnable()
        {
            selectables = FindObjectsOfType<Selectable>().Where(s => s.interactable && !s.transform.IsChildOf(transform)).ToArray();
            foreach (var selectable in selectables)
            {
                selectable.interactable = false;
                //Debug.Log($"{selectable} disabled");
            }
        }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            if (selectables == null)
                return;

            foreach (var selectable in selectables)
                selectable.interactable = true;
            selectables = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will also have to handle Prefabs, but the idea is good.